# How could I optimize the objective function which is a probability form

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Recently, I am trying to solve a stochastic planning problem. The problem is like this:

$$
\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n,x\geq0}\quad \varphi(x) = \mathbb{P}[\xi\leq b+Ax] \\ Cx\leq d
$$

In this problem, $Cx\leq d$ is linear constraints, which is not a trouble in solving this problem. However, $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a Gaussian random vector with variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and mean $\mu$.

As I don't want to find the exact solution to this problem, the maximum objective function is certainly 1. I just want to find an $x$ to make sure the probability larger than a certain value, say 0.98. In other words, I want to formulate this optimization problem as a feasibility problem. However, I don't know how to deal with this objective function which is actually a cumulative multinormal distribution function.

I cannot find any useful material to solve this problem. I would appreciate that if you could give me some suggestion or recommend me some book or paper to read.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer had a flaw and the correct answer is that the problem is intractable as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: You really gave me a way of solving this problem!  About the first step, in which you formed the standard multivariate normal, is there any book or paper I can refer to? I just learned how to standardize a variable which follows a normal distribution. However, I didn't know how to standardize a Random Vector. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know who originally came up with the whitening transform, but the following notes look promising and should help with your understanding. http://courses.media.mit.edu/2010fall/mas622j/whiten.pdf

Comment: Excuse me, professor. I tried to solve the quasiconcave optimization problem by the bisection method with YALMIP, but I failed. I posted my question in the YALMIP forum(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yalmip/F1AlMeu0urY ). Professor Johan replied me that this problem was a nonconvex problem and it was intractable generally. Now, I feel really confused about how to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you for your help!!!