# Should the probability of multivariate normal be the same before and after whitening transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

I would like to solve a Probability problem: $\mathbb{P}[\xi\leq Ax+b]$, where $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(\begin{bmatrix}1\\6\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0.6 & 0.02\\0.02 &0.5\end{bmatrix})$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 3\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$,  $x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1.5\end{bmatrix}$, $b=\begin{bmatrix}-6\\-2\end{bmatrix}$.

I use the 'mvncdf.m' in matlab to solve this probability as follows,

`AA = [5,3;3,4];
bb = [-6;-2];
x_s = [0;1.5];
avg= [1;6];
div = [0.6,0.02;0.02,0.5];
test = AA*x_s+bb;
test = test';
aa = -inf*ones(1,2); 
avg_1 = avg';
eta_test = mvncdf(aa,test,avg_1,div);`

The answer of this problem is 2.1496e-06;

However, I found another way to transform the non-standard multivariate normal distribution into a normal one. The name of the method is called: [Whitening transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516042/how-could-i-optimize-the-objective-function-which-is-a-probability-form/2517775#2517775).

I used this method to solve the whitening matrix as well as the probability of the new problem. The programs are shown as follows:

`[uu,vv] = eig(div); 
W = vv^(-1/2)*uu;
kk = W*AA*x_s+W*(bb-avg);
eta_trans = mvncdf(kk);`

However, the probability of this problem is 0.9827.

At first, I thought this transformation should be equivalent, which means they could get the same probability. I didn't know why they return the different value.

Looking forward to receiving your help. Thanks a lot!!!